# For each item in an array using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Say I have this command:

```
kbc get pods -o=json | jq -c
```

which gives me something like:

```
{"apiVersion":"v1","items":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"}]}
```

how can I echo the name for each element in the items array? Something like this:

```
kbc get pods -o=json | jq -c | jq '.items[].name' | cat
```

Comment: `echo "$1"`? What would that even *do*?

Comment: Keep in mind that all `echo` does is write something to stdout (in theory; it actually has a bunch of extra, platform-dependent, poorly-specified behaviors, which is why the POSIX `echo` spec suggests using `printf` instead). `jq` writes its output to stdout already, so there's no reason to capture it and then rewrite.

Comment: yeah echo can't read from stdin no matter what, so I will change to cat

Comment: Though I'm unclear on why you'd have a `cat` step; the output is the same as the input, so why do anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kbc get pods -o=json | jq -r '.items[].name'
```

Using `-r` tells jq to write *raw* output, thus without quoting the names as JSON strings.

Comment: Yeah I saw this: `kbc get pods -o=json | jq -r '.items[] | .name'` notice the pipe between `.items[] | .name`,  so I guess that pipe is not necessary?

Comment: Correct; identical behavior either way.

Comment: Do you happen to know what it's identical? what's the rhyme/reason?

Comment: Are you asking why the `|` isn't mandatory, or why it's permitted at all? Because the answer to "what's the rhyme/reason?" pretty much falls out from those two design questions.

Comment: Yeah why it's not mandatory

Comment: ...because the syntax isn't ambiguous / unparsable without it, and syntactic sugar that increases terseness without creating ambiguity is in at least some language design circles considered a good thing?

Comment: If you want an answer that gets into implementation details, https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/parser.y is your go-to; as you can see, `block_join()` is called both in the `[].` case and in the `|` case.

Comment: I will just have to read what the pipe operator is supposed to do, never seen it before there, yeah thx for that link